# How to efficiently evaluate Exp[I m θ]

Tags: performance-tuning, complex

The I is imaginary number. My question is when m becomes large and the number of θ increases, how to evaluate it faster.

Here is one way to get the result and store all the value it found.

```
exp[I, 0, theta_] := 1.;
exp[I, 1, theta_] := Exp[I theta];
exp[i_, m_, theta_] := 
  exp[i, m, theta] = exp[I , (m - 1), theta]*exp[I, 1, theta];
```

this uses the method:

```
Exp(I*m*θ)=Exp(I*(m-1)*θ)*Exp(I*θ).
```

Comment: Why don't you just use `Exp` directly?

Comment: it is too slow to evaluate thousands of θ @Szabolcs

Comment: @look Can you edit your question and add a small representative code example that we can do a performance measurement on and see what can be improved? I'm saying that because usually there are lots of different opportunities to optimize, and it's hard to say what's most relevant to your use case without seeing more code.

Comment: Can you give a specific example where a single call to the `Exp` function is too slow?

Comment: @look - On my laptop `Do[m = RandomInteger[{100, 1000}]; theta = RandomReal[{1000, 10000}]; 
  Exp[I*m*theta], 100000] // AbsoluteTiming` evaluates in about 0.28 seconds.

Comment: I think you are right, Thanks@BobHanlon

Comment: I voted to close this question as unclear, as I do not understand what you are trying to accomplish. You seem to _suggest_ that the `Exp` function is too slow, but you have not confirmed that this is indeed the issue after multiple comments, and have not provided an example which demonstrates the bad performance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`RSolve`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/RSolve.html) to get a closed form from the recursion definition. Also, the result is then not limited to positive, integer values of m.

```
exp[m_, theta_] = 
 f[m, theta] /. 
  RSolve[{f[0, theta] == 1, f[m, theta] == f[m - 1, theta]*Exp[I*theta]}, 
    f[m, theta], {m, theta}][[1]]

(* (E^(I theta))^m *)
```

Answer (score 1):

The form in the title of the question is about twice as fast as the form in @BobHanlon's answer, if `Exp` is computed in a vectorized way:

```
Block[{theta = RandomReal[10, 10^6], m = 10000},
 (E^(I theta))^m; // RepeatedTiming
 ]
(*  {0.033, Null}  *)

Block[{theta = RandomReal[10, 10^6], m = 10000},
 (E^(I m theta)); // RepeatedTiming
 ]
(*  {0.013, Null}  *)
```

Comment: `(E^(I theta))^m` is the form that `RSolve` returns. To get the other form use `PowerExpand`

Comment: @BobHanlon Sure, but I thought the OP's concern was about making `Exp[I*m*θ]` faster, which the OP claims [in a comment](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/186322/how-to-efficiently-evaluate-expi-m-θ/186344?noredirect=1#comment485440_186322) is too slow. It seems to me that a faster way has not been found yet.